# How to get a group type using Google Apps APIs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I'm currently developing a Google Apps Script that modifies the settings of all groups of a domain, but the settings applied depend on the group type (i.e. email list or collaborative inbox, mostly).

However, I've not found a way to determine the group type using the Google APIs (I'm using the ["Groups Settings API"](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/) and the ["Directory API: Groups"](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list)).

Does anyone know how to get the group type using the Google APIs, or any other programmatic way ?

Answer (score 1):

These group 'types' aren't really types - because of this, there's nothing in the Groups Settings API to set or get the type.

Essentially, when you change between them, Google Groups is just changing a bunch of presets. The only way to tell the difference would be to create different test groups for each 'type', GET the settings for each with the Groups Settings API and use any difference in settings between them as how you determine the 'type' of the group.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. We tried that, but sadly we get exactly the same settings for both this way. The "Groups Settings API" doesn't expose all settings, so I guess that the interesting ones are not  included.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case but didn't have time to test myself. Maybe something could be added to the description of the group as that can be pulled programmatically (Directory API)?

Comment: That's indeed our final conclusion. That, or parsing the UI (or using something like selenium) but that's not a road we want to take.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the group types by selecting the very group..after that..goto SETTINGS SYMBOL-->by going to the GROUP setting in right side of dropdown menu of SETTINGS ..

then in the left side you will find ADVANCE option TAG under the "INFORMATION" COLLAPSIBLE TAG in where you can change the google group type to any of the four thing